# R program cannot install new packages

Tags: r, package

I newly installed R-program 3.6.0. after removing my older version which cannot run some new packages. Since this new installment, however, my R program does not proceed installing new packages stopping at this command line:

```
 utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
```

Thereafter, I was expecting selecting country and city to choose the site to install packages but did not see this pop up window anymore.

May I get help on this please?

Comment: Are you using rstudio?

Comment: This is an error from R x64 3.6.0. icon which is a non-rstudio approach.

Comment: I think that was the first reported / recognised bug after the R 3.6.0 release.  You can resort to installing programmatically or by calling `install.packages()` -- just the menu is hosed.

Comment: This is the bug not from my mistake which will be fixed later on?

Comment: Yes. And it _may_ already be fixed in a R 3.6.0-patched build. Check the mailing -- I didn't follow this all that closely as I am a) on Linux and b) prefer `install.packages()`.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you so much for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in R 3.6.0 as commented in the original question.

You can bypass this by typing

```
install.packages()
```

from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

stopping at this command line -> You can click "Esc" to jump out, then try again to run command line. If not this question, can you tell me which system do you setup, then I try to find your question?